# Find next empty cell in a range?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the next empty cell in a range, starting from a specific column and then trying to put in todays date.

Code:

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = Now()
```

My Range to check for blank cells is V to X.

So for instance if i had a spreadsheet that looked like below:

```
Column U                                                                  Column V                                                           Column W                                                 Column X
Start checking blanks from here but don't check this column itself        I'm Not a blank Cell so move to the next cell and check            I'm a blank cell. Put value here                         I am a blank cell. I will have a value placed in me next time
```

At the moment my code is putting the date in the first blank cell in a row starting from  column A. This is obviously not correct.

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: just use .End(xlLeft).End(xlLeft).

Comment: @Lowpar not sure how you mean for me to use this? I tried ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlLeft).End(xlLeft).Value = Now() but this didn't work either

Comment: Are you sure the cells are blank? Because if the cell is blank and you ctrl+left to the direct you should find the next blank, either that or you can use the .find function or loop through all the cells.

Comment: I don't think the End method is the best for this. Traverse the range instead, and check for blank

Answer (score 0):

Change xlleft to **xlToLeft**

I recommend to used usedrange rows count than simple sheet.rows.count for your requirement.

ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count,"U").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)